# erlang- how to compile&load external module within a code

Tags: compilation, erlang

I want to compile&load **mod.erl** from **test_mod.erl**

i tried to do this:

```
 -module(mod_test).
 -export([test/0]).   

 test()->
         compile:file(mod),
         mod:start().
```

but if its not doing the job

Comment: What's return `compile:file(mod),`?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not doing the job"? Does it behave incorrectly? Do you get an error message?

Comment: @legoscia - actually its compile&run it only if it wasnt compiled before.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put expressions on the top level of a module; you need to enclose them in a function, like this:

```
-module(mod_test).

-export([compile_and_load_mod/0]).

compile_and_load_mod() ->
    compile:file(mod),
    mod:start().
```

Then you can call `mod_test:compile_and_load_mod()`.

Comment: sure, i just simplified it